# styling scrollbar works perfect on chrome and safari but not on mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Scrollbar working fine in chrome and safari but in mozilla its not working the way it should, below is my code, i could have done this easily using jquery or javaScript but looking for css solution first.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 5px; }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {width: 8px;height:5px;}
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background:none;}
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background:#000;}
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {background:#000;}
```

Comment: try google searching : ' what does webkit mean ' . and you will get your answer > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla doesn't support custom CSS scrollbar, try a plugin like [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

[::-webkit-scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) is only available in WebKit-based browsers (e.g., Google Chrome).
It is not supported in Firefox, please check [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar).